# Find object with given value in normalized object of key value pairs

Tags: javascript, redux, key-value

Say I have a normalized object (as you often see when working with redux) containing key value pairs like this:

```
const normalized_object = {
  "1": {
    id: "1",
    color: "red",
    other_id: "45"
  },
  "2": {
    id: "2",
    color: "blue",
    other_id: "101"
  },
  "3": {
    id: "3",
    color: "green",
    other_id: "77"
  }
};
```

What is the best way to retrieve the inner object that has a given `other_id`. Something like the following:

```
const inner_obj = normalized_object.find(entry => entry.other_id === "77");
console.log(inner_obj);

// Prints the third inner object with id "3"
```

Is there a one-liner for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
const normalized_object = {
  "1": { id: "1", color: "red", other_id: "45" },
  "2": { id: "2", color: "blue", other_id: "101" },
  "3": { id: "3", color: "green", other_id: "77" }
};

const inner_obj = Object.values(normalized_object).find(entry => entry.other_id === "77");

console.log(inner_obj);
```